# url redirect not working properly

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, mod-alias

I am using below rule to redirect my url

```
Redirect 301 /crm /crm/applications
```

But the resulting url because of rule is

```
http://www.site_url.com/crm/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications/applications
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**RedirectMatch**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#RedirectMatch) instead,

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/crm$ /crm/applications
```

It provides regular expression based match which can help zero down on specific pattern using `^` and `$` anchors.

Comment: thank you for reply... but the solution not work for me

Comment: There is no error ..... it still showing same url ( with multiple "/applications" as mention in question )